# Shortcode for specific blog post/posts in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

I am having a trouble finding a way to create a shortcode for specific blog posts in wordpress.

What I want to create is a way to display,

1. latest post
2. 2nd to latest post
3. 3rd to latest post
4. 4th to latest post

I know there are ways to display blog posts by listing them up, But I want to display them individually, so that I can place them in different parts of the pre-made theme.

Is there anyway to make this possible?

Thank you for your time! :)

Answer (score 0):

```
function latest_blog_posts(){
ob_start(); ?>
//use wp_query where you can have parameters 'order'=>'desc'
or you can use wordpress neat function wp_get_recent_posts()
<?php
$contents=ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
return $contents;   
}

add_shortcode('latest_blog_posts','latest_blog_posts');
```

and paste your code wherever you want to

```
<?php echo do_shortcode('[latest_blog_posts]'); ?>
```

or you can directly paste it on editor as well